# Showing a convolution is Lipschitz. In measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution, lipschitz-functions, jensen-inequality

Let $\Lambda:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$, be Lipschitz. Is the convolution of $\Lambda$ with a measure Lipshchitz? That is do we have

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \| \Lambda*\rho(x) - \Lambda*\mu(x)\|^2 ~ d\rho(x) \leq C W_2^2(\mu,\rho)
$$

for some $C>0$, and $W_2$ the Wasserstein metric, and $\mu,\rho$ probability measures. My attempt : let $Y\sim \rho, Z\sim \mu$

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \| \Lambda*\rho(x) - \Lambda*\mu(x)\|^2 ~ d\rho(x) =& \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\Lambda(x-y)\big(\rho(y)-\mu(y)\big) dy\|^2 ~ d\rho(x) 
\\
=& \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \| \mathbb{E}[\Lambda(x-Y)-\Lambda(x-Z)] \|^2 ~ d\rho(x) 
\\
\leq&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{E}[\|\Lambda(x-Y)-\Lambda(x-Z)\|^2]  ~ d\rho(x)
\\
\leq&C \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbb{E}[\|Y-Z\|^2]  ~ d\rho(x)=C \mathbb{E}[\|Y-Z\|^2].
\end{align}

Is this ok?

Comment: What is $W_2^2$?

Comment: @PhoemueX the wasserstein metric squared

Comment: I'm here, let me take a look, thanks for calling me!

Comment: I think this proof works!